# how to layout this page?

Tags: android, css

I want to layout one page like this: [screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf7VN.png), [screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSVsK.png).

The page includes three sections -- header (orange section), content (pink section), footer (blue section) --
The header and footer will be fixed on the screen. The content will scroll when needed.At the same time, when you focus any of the three inputs (located in the different sections), the keyboard can't cover the input, neither do the other section.

I have tried some methods, but I can't find a perfect method compatible with all the mobile browsers.

In china there is a quirk browser called UC, in version 9.0 UC when the keyboard displays, there is a blank area at the end of page. This blank area won't disapper until you touch the screen and scroll the page, [like this the blank area in the end of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yL15k.png).

I inspected this area thrown winer, the blank area isn`t a part of the HTML, have been confused by this problem .

I need your help!
Any suggestions?

I have tried this layout:

html:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    {{wing.view('pages/demo/css')}}

</head>
<body>

<div id="doc">
    <div class="header">this is header
        <div>input some chinese chars:<input type="text"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">this is content
        <div>input some chinese chars:
            数学库 - 开源中国社区
            Math.js 是个JavaScript 和写真—Tag—电影网—www.M...  电影网
            <input type="text"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">this is footer
        <div>input some chinese chars:<input type="text"/></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

css(less):

```css
 @import url(../lang/base.less);

html, body, #wing-page-content, #doc {
  height: 100%;
}

#doc {
  .display();
  .flex-direction(column);

}

.content {
  .flex();
  background-color: #f99690;
}

.header {
  height: 44px;
  background-color: #e76000;
}

.footer {
  height: 44px;
  background-color: #0073FD;
}

.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

}
```

base.less--->https://github.com/codio/Flex.less/blob/master/flex.less

Comment: Can you show your code? What have you tried so far? Also please mind the formatting, your question looks very confusing. Is this for a web page or an Android app?

Comment: this is for app which is a hybird app. this page should run at the android app and ios app.The android app`s webview is based on the UC broswer webkit kernel.and the ios app is based on the ios sdk webkit.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <body style="height:100%; width:100%">
    <div id="header" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; height:200px; right:0px;overflow:hidden;"> 
    </div> 
    <div id="content" style="position:absolute; top:200px; bottom:200px; left:0px; right:0px; overflow:auto;"> 
    </div> 
    <div id="footer" style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; height:200px; left:0px; right:0px; overflow:hidden;"> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```